# Нужно решить проблему с кириллицей в имени пользователя

Tags: windows

В общем история проста. Я купил новый компьютер и на радостях ввёл имя пользователя на кириллице. И теперь иногда сталкиваюсь с проблемами. В интернетах есть гайды как переименовать пользователя, но там на каждом этапе капсом написаны угрозы, что так делать не стоит. Также, есть инфа, что нужно создать нового пользователя с именем на латиннице, но последовательности действий как "переехать" полностью со старого на нового пользователя нет. Я понимаю, что это максимально тупой вопрос, но давайте уже предостережем таких же чайников как я и напишем полноценную инструкцию, как поступать, если ты создал пользователя с кириллицей в имени

OS: Windows 11 Pro

Comment: А в чем проблема ника на кириллице? У меня никогда с таким ником проблем не возникало.

Comment: Создаёшь нового пользователя на латинице. Все личные файлы хранишь на D:\. Закладки браузера синкаешь через облако этого браузера. Всё остальное - костыли.